# PLC to SQL Server data loss

Tags: arrays, sql-server, database, plc, data-loss

I'm in charge of a project where we need to collect data (11 tags) from a PLC and write them into a SQL database in 5 ms increments.

This is the first project where such a high sampling rate is required, and we only collect about 5 - 10% of data with our usual configuration (Rockwell Allen-Bradley CompactLogix PLC --> Kepware KEPserver --> VB.NET desktop app --> MS SQL). I've searched the Internet and found some third party products (SQL4automation, Kepware DataLogger plugin, RSLinx, Ignition) which promise lossless data transfer from a PLC directly to a DB, but they are all very costly.

Has anybody found an (ideally free) solution to a similar problem? We are currently rewriting our PLC and desktop apps to write the data into two separate arrays and copying it alternately - has anybody had any success with this method?

If not - any experience with 3rd party software?

Thanks for the help,
Dugi

Comment: 5ms is very high rate considering all the delays involved... I really think having a data buffer on the PLC memory in such cases is the norm. The buffer should even contain more than just 2 "snapshots" of the tags IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved polling rates down to 10ms from standard PC and Siemens PLC without any special config to increase performance (buffers on plc, ...)

Take a look at:   Snap7 - [Step7 Ethernet Communication Suite](http://snap7.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks P.A., the solution you proposed does look promising for Siemens controllers and might come in handy in the future. However, we chose a Rockwell (Allen Bradley) PLC for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Wonderware Historian would give you the resolution.  The drivers can actually log data and trigger off of changes.  The data is also automatically compressed.  With Historian you could then query the SQL database at 5ms increments and get back valid, real data.  However, Historian is anything but free.

Short of this, I'd store all of the data in the PLC.  For example, a whole second at the 5ms intervals.  Then transfer that information over to SQL every second or so.